# Loading a CSV file into QGIS without longitude or latitude data

Tags: qgis, geometry, csv

I am trying to load a CSV table into QGIS. There are no longitude or latitude values and the options for X and Y axis look like this:

[image]

These are fields in the table I am trying to load. and this is the file:

https://data.london.gov.uk/download/land-use-ward/1f9be3a5-7ea7-4996-8875-fa060d8335e4/Land%20use%20borough.csv

Answer (score 6):

The data is for London Boroughs.

So you need a file of London Boroughs that you can load into QGIS, and then you can join your CSV onto that spatial file.

You can get a ShapeFile of Boroughs from:

https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london

statistical-gis-boundaries-london.zip

In the ESRI folder you can find: London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp

Just drag and drop that into QGIS.

Also drag and drop the CSV "Land use borough" into QGIS, it should show as a non-spatial table in the layers panel:

[image]

Then right click on the London_Borough_Excluding_MHW layer, and choose Properties. And go to the Joins tab.

Click on the green plus at the bottom left.

And we will set up the join as seen:

[image]

This will join the first set of values from your CSV to the Borough boundaries. Which is Domestic Buildings.

All the joined fields are treated as stings as default, so one tip if you want to use a graduated symbology on the percentage would to use the to_real function as seen:

[image]

For the rest of data in the CSV the easiest way to create layers from them would be to edit the CSV into one CSV per attribute.

Comment: thank you for your help! i will try this :)

Answer (score 3):

This file does not have geometry informations, so you need to load it as no geometry. Also check "first record has fieldnames", set "number of header lines to discard" to 0 and uncheck decimal separator as comma (the area_m2 field has float values separated by comma, but is formatted as string), then load it:

[image]

If you need this as a spatial table, your best bet is to get a spatial file of "local authorities" somewhere, which allows an attribute join via "Area Code" or "Local Authority Name".

Comment: ok thank you! i'm gonna give this a go... thanks a lot